# Cannot send mail using smtp.gmail.com from ONLY one specific Google account

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, gmail-api

I am not able to send mail via smtp.gmail.com for **ONLY** one specific Google account. When I use another Google account my VBS script sends mail successfully so I know the script is working correctly.

- Both accounts have the [Less Secure Apps](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps) turned ON.
- I have also tried the [Display Unlock Captcha](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/displayunlockcaptcha) multiple times.
- [POP](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7104828?hl=en&vid=0-867173084911-1512103332561) and [IMAP](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en&vid=0-867173084911-1512103332561) has been enabled for both accounts.

It looks like there is an issue with that particular account and I have already posted a request for support in the Gmail help forums.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/8XFKONFbDA8

My VBS Script:

```
Dim emailObj
Set emailObj = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

emailObj.From     = "******@gmail.com"
emailObj.To       = "******@gmail.com"

emailObj.Subject  = "Test Email"
emailObj.TextBody = "Testing Email Functionality"

Set emailConfig = emailObj.Configuration

emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")            = "smtp.gmail.com"
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")        = 465
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")             = 2
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate")      = 1
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl")            = true

'First Account
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername")          = "******@gmail.com"
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword")          = "************"

'Second Account
'emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername")          = "******@gmail.com"
'emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword")          = "************"

emailConfig.Fields.Update
emailObj.Send

If err.number = 0 Then
    Msgbox "Done"
Else
    Msgbox err
End If
```

**Account 1 Test (Not Working)**

[image: Account 1]

**Account 2 Test (Working)**

[image: Account 2]

**Error Message:** The message could not be sent to the SMTP server. The transport error code was 0x80040217. The server response was not available

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying that you can't send a message when using 'a certain email' but works on other emails? What error logs are you getting?

Comment: Yes that's correct. I have posted an image with the error message. I have also edited the post to display the error message as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same error. There is an option in Google account - https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps. I turned it On and it helped me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but one of the things that I mentioned in my question was that: Both accounts have the Less Secure Apps turned ON.